# Kids names in Empire (TV show)

Tags: empire

In the TV Series Empire, Lucious, which seems to be Christian name, had children with his ex-wife, Cookie, not sure what kind of a name that is. Their kids have names - Hakeem and Jamal, both of which seem to be Muslim names. The third kid is Andre, which again seems to be Christian.

Is there a reason that has been disclosed behind their names?
Were they all born to the same parents?

Answer (score 1):

Let's visit the Empire Wikia, shall we:

> [Lucious Lyon (born **Dwight Walker**)](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Lucious_Lyon) *[...]* is the father of sons [Andre](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Andre_Lyon), [Jamal](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Jamal_Lyon) and [Hakeem](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Hakeem_Lyon) Lyon with his ex-wife [Cookie Lyon](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Cookie_Lyon), as well as a daughter, [Lola Lyon](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Lola_Lyon) with his ex-lover and ex-daughter in law [Olivia Lyon](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Olivia_Lyon).
>
> [...]
>
> Believing that a black kid with the name "Dwight Walker" wouldn't survive living on the streets, he took on the name 'Lucious Lyon', believing that one day that would be the name of an immortal god.

I don't think you need to look for a religious background for the names of his children, they're fairly common names. It's not like we nowadays assume a religious reason when someone names their kid Mary or Joseph (unless they have both a son and daughter and name them Mary and Joseph).

WRT Cookie, again let's visit Wikia:

> [Loretha "Cookie" Lyon](http://empire.wikia.com/wiki/Cookie_Lyon)

So Cookie is a nickname. Perhaps from her youth, perhaps from when she was a drugdealer? It's not specified in the Wikia, so I'm guessing its origins have not been discussed in the show.